# Can't connect to Samba drive in CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, samba

```
#smbclient //ballzdeep/torrents
Server not using user level security and no password supplied
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

Does this mean I would need to require a username and password for my drive? Windows and Ubuntu connect to it with their GUIs, but I can't get CentOS 6.3 to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to create some kind of credentials file and use it when you mount cifs/samba shares. Here is an example using fstab

```
# insecure and common usage
//share/dir /mnt/myshare cifs username=user,password=pass

# more secure usage
Create a credentials file in /etc/ that has 0600 permissions for root.
Call it fileshare

//share/dir /mt/myshare cifs credentials=/etc/fileshare

cat /etc/fileshare
username=yourusername
password=youpass
```

You can then mount it by hand if you like by doing this.

```
smbmount //share/dir /mnt/myshare -o credentials=/etc/fileshare
```